# RDLC Report taking too long to get rendered for Large Records

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, rdlc

I am offering user to download data report using RDLCs. Corresponding DB contains 500 000 records. After fetching records from DB. When I call render method of Report Manager it takes too long to respond (12-15 mins). That does not seems to be a good behavior from user perspective. 
What can I do to reduce rendering time of report?

Here is code snippet:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streams;
byte[] renderedBytes;

//Render the report
renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
```

Comment: You may need to post your queries bound to RDLC.  With this information, it is hard to understand your issue especially performance issues.  What did you try so far to tweak it?

Comment: yes.  but i think queries are not an issue. that is taking reasonable time of 5-6 seconds only. Main concern comes when i  provide data source to report manager.